# CSS highlight label BEFORE an invalid input

Tags: css

Ciao, I have this element here:

```
<div class="uk-form-row">
    <div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-filled md-input-focus">
        <label>Label</label>
        <input type="text" class="md-input">
        <span class="md-input-bar"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is from a material design theme ([Altair Admin v2](http://altair_html.tzdthemes.com/forms_regular.html)) so the element once the page is loaded does this:

[image]

As you can see the label is moving around (but maybe is not a big deal).

With other elements, if they are empty (invalid) I can underline them or change their color using css:

```
input:invalid::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: #e53935 !important;
}
```

But being this a label BEFORE the input I don't know how I can select it with CSS. How do I turn the LABEL into a different color if the input is invalid?

Comment: This label is positioned absolutely - you can put `label` _after_ `input` and use css sibling selector.

Comment: @fen1x ok can you give me an example of "css sibling selector"?

Comment: something like `input:invalid ~ label { color: red; }`. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Comment: @Mr.Web - I just checked http://altair_html.tzdthemes.com/forms_regular.html - and it seems like you can change the markup with the label AFTER the input without breaking any functionality. Did you try that? (If that's not viable, then I'm afraid this can't be done with just CSS)

Comment: Yep, tried it in Chrome DevTools - it _seems_ to work fine. Didn't dig deep into this particular theme though, so something _may_ be broken.

Comment: @fen1x and Danield tried and not working, as the label, when moved after the input messes all up. See result here: https://snag.gy/dXivgs.jpg as you can see the label is UNDER the input and not working properly anymore.

Comment: @Mr.Web Check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/aVyMEo?editors=1000) - order elements doesn't change label behaviour. I took css from the theme site.

Comment: @fen1x you are right, I had a slightly different code. I'll try it out! If you want to post it as an answer will be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at CSS code (simplified to illustrate my point):

```
.md-input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.md-input-wrapper > label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 4px;
  right: 0;
}
```

Label is positioned absolutely relative to wrapper, so you can put `label` element after `input` element in HTML:

```
<div class="md-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="md-input">
    <span class="md-input-bar"></span>
    <label>Label</label>
</div>
```

After that, you can use [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to select label of invalid input:

```
input:invalid ~ label { 
   color: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler way to get this done. The `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-classes will automatically bubble up to a parent `<fieldset>`. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) is the reference.

You can take advantage of this fact to style your label like so:

```
<fieldset>
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
```

Then in your CSS

```
fieldset:invalid > label:first-of-type {
  color: #e53935 !important;
}
```

So if your input is `:invalid` it will invalidate your fieldset, which you can then reference to style your label.

Comment: This looks awesome, but how is the support ? caniuse.com does not have data on this ... which is sad because this looks like the perfect solution